# How do I list the cloud functions based on user labels?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I see in the ListFunctions calls, it is returning all the functions in the project and specified region. I would like to filter by labels and I don't see the ListFunctionsRequest accept the filter, to filter it by labels. Any suggestions?
Something like what gcloud CLI supports: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/list

Documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/functions/apiv1#CloudFunctionsClient.ListFunctions

Code from docs

````
ctx := context.Background()
    c, err := functions.NewCloudFunctionsClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: Handle error.
    }
    defer c.Close()

    req := &functionspb.ListFunctionsRequest{
        // TODO: Fill request struct fields.
    }
    it := c.ListFunctions(ctx, req)
    for {
        resp, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            // TODO: Handle error.
        }
        // TODO: Use resp.
        _ = resp
    }```
````

Comment: I do not know the answer in this case. Some APIs support `filters`, some do not or do not support all filter use cases. If the CLI supports a filter and the API does not, then the filter is implemented inside the CLI. That means you would also need to duplicate that filtering feature inside your code. To verify, create a CLI command and add the command line option `--log-http` to see that actual REST API call. If the filter is not passed to the API, then you know a) that you must write that filter code, or b) how the filter is encoded in the API call.

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Functions API [doesn't support filter query parameter](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/list)

The gcloud filtering is performed by the CLI and not by the API. Therefore, if you use the API directly, you need to reimplement this filter feature.